# how can I remove direct debit payment option from PayPal Plus's payment selection page

Tags: paypal, paypal-plus

I have integrated PayPal Plus that is working fine. But as per PayPal plus its showing payment selection option wall that is showing by default three options - 1 - PayPal 2 - Direct debit 3 - credit card

I want to remove direct debit as our system doesn't want to get payments from direct debit, how can I remove Direct Debit payment option from PayPal Plus's payment selection page ?
I have tried to read out PayPal plus documentation and try to find out what would be the possible ways to remove direct debit. but I could not find one. any insight would be really appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I checked with someone familiar with PayPal Plus integrations in Germany, and this is not possible to do. You cannot disable individual payment methods, you either get them all or you go back to the basic PayPal option.

Comment: Yes, I have read this on PayPal community Platform, But This is so sick we can't have an option to choose, I tried a lot with JavaScript and CSS to at least hide the option but that is also not possible because we could not have authority to change  I frame, It is not accessible from PayPal

Comment: You might try https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server as an alternative , it does let you disable particular buttons: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#disable-funding